# Ctrl + click old behavior on table names

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

On PhpStorm 2017.1, when I `Ctrl + Click` a table name on a query, the table is selected on the database panel. On 2017.2 it opens a new tab on the editor with the DDL for create the table.

How can I go back to the old behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same behavior. This should be reported to JetBrains tracker as a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes

Comment: I don't think that this is a bug.... a feature, maybe. A shortcut chang. I've posted on the community forum.

Answer (score 0):

For me ctrl + alt + left click brings me to the table data panel. Maybe it will work for you too. Took me awhile to find that.

Comment: It worked, but is a different shortcut. This opens a new tab with table data, like you said. The shortcut I'm talking about opens the database panel, with all tables and works with columns too. Thanks